# What do I need to do to be able to upload more levels?

Tags: super-mario-maker

I've almost reached the level upload cap, and while I was hoping that my tenth star might net me a new badge and allow me to upload more levels...it did not.

I've assumed that my next badge would allow me to upload more levels, but what I'm really asking here is not how to get my next badge (since I don't know what will actually happen if I do), but what is actually needed to upload more than 10 levels.

So, what do I need to do to unlock the ability to upload more than 10 levels?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to reddit user [/u/ZMerik](https://www.reddit.com/user/ZMerik), you'll need quite a bit [more stars to increase your upload cap](https://www.reddit.com/r/MarioMaker/comments/3ksbmb/how_many_stars_do_you_need_to_increase_your_level/cv0bj60):

> Start: 10 Levels
>   50 Stars: 20 Levels
>   150 Stars: 30 Levels
>   300 Stars: 40 Levels
>   500 Stars: 50 Levels
>   800 Stars: 60 Levels
>   1300 Stars: 70 Levels

Note that this doesn't mean you need to earn an average of 5 stars on every level you upload for the first level cap increase. As pointed out by other redditors in [the same thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MarioMaker/comments/3ksbmb/how_many_stars_do_you_need_to_increase_your_level/), you keep the stars even if you remove the level you uploaded from the server.

Comment: This answer is better than mine. I didn't know there was anything above 300. +1